# Android - SherlockActionBar long press icon menu

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, long-press

I'm trying to listen on a long click in actionbarsherlock. The default action is to show an empty toast. I don't know how to change those actions like display a dialog or something like this.
I have for example on the bar (Sherlock) an icon that says sync. I would like this button to show a toast when the user makes a long press

Thanks ! :)

Comment: If you add titles to your action items the toast wouldn't be empty!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See an answer from library developer (Jake Wharton) [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionbarsherlock/lU4yrwz47o4/fmZQkiTA8i4J). In a nutshell,

> It is not possible. The long press is reserved for toasting an action
>   item's title.

Answer (score 0):

You can start an action upon user's click and in that you can run a clock and identify time and if time if more (let's say 10 say) you can show a tost.. if less do nothing.

you can trap long press using timeinterval in that case.

I hope this helps. Thanks

Better you can check this [article that explain](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) what it takes to deliver the above.